# Why does the progressbar accelerate whenever activity restarts

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

I have a question about the progress bar. There is activity with question and answers. When user click on one of those answers. activity calls itself and generate new question with answers. In the header, I have progress bar, and the progress bar is full for N seconds. Every time the activity calls itself, the progress bar is full for N/2 seconds. I want to the progress bar to be full for N seconds, not for N/2. If you can help me, I'd be grateful. Problem is in the `curiProgress` function. Here is my code.

```
{
public class beze2 extends Activity{

    String FILENAME = "HighScore";
    FileOutputStream fos;
    private boolean tocan = false;
    private int c, progressStatus=400, id_odgovor, rezultat;
    private myCountDownTimer timer;
    private static int myProgress=400;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Handler myHandler=new Handler();
    private TextView text, t;
    private int[] b;
    private String d, f, strin;
    private ArrayList numbers;
    private ArrayList<Pitanja> pitanja; 
    private ArrayList<Odgovor> odgovori;
    private TestAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Random r;
    private LinearLayout ln;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getIntents();
        initializeVariables();
        dodajVrijednostiUb();
        postaviPitanje();
        postaviOdgovore();
        curiProgress();
    }

    private void getIntents(){

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String reza = i.getStringExtra("REZULTAT");
        strin = i.getStringExtra("EXTRA_M");
        rezultat = Integer.parseInt(reza);

    }



    private void initializeVariables(){

        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.myProgress);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vrijeme);
        timer = new myCountDownTimer(20*1000,1*1000);
        numbers = new ArrayList();
        mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);         
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
        mDbHelper.open();
        pitanja = mDbHelper.getPitanje(Integer.parseInt(strin));
        b = new int[pitanja.size()];
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_pitanja);
        myProgress=400;
        r = new Random();
        progressBar.setMax(400);
        ln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutOdgovori);
        buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    }

    private void curiProgress(){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(progressStatus>=0)
                {
                    progressStatus=performTask();
                    myHandler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                    public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                    });

                }
                myHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       progressStatus=0; 
                       myProgress=0;

                    }
                });

            }
            private int performTask()
            {
                try {
                    //---Do some task---
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return --myProgress;    
            }
        }).start();

    }

    private void dodajVrijednostiUb(){

        for (int z=0;z<pitanja.size(); z++){
            b[z] = pitanja.get(z).getId_pitanja();
            numbers.add(b[z]);
        }

    }

    private void postaviPitanje(){

        while (!numbers.contains(c)){
            c = r.nextInt(22) + 1;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<pitanja.size(); i++){
            if (c==b[i]){
                d = pitanja.get(i).getTekst_pitanja();
                id_odgovor = pitanja.get(i).getOdgovor();
            }
        }
        t.setText(d);

    }

    private void postaviOdgovore(){

        odgovori = mDbHelper.getOdgovor(c);
        for (int i = 0; i<odgovori.size(); i++){

            final Button bt = new Button(this);
            bt.setId(odgovori.get(i).getId_odgovor());
            bt.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier("buttoni", "drawable", getPackageName()));
            final String text = odgovori.get(i).getOdgovor();
            int l = odgovori.get(i).getId_odgovor();
            final String s = Integer.toString(l);
            bt.setText(text);
            buttonParams.setMargins(20, 5, 20, 5);
            bt.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
            ln.addView(bt);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    f = Integer.toString(id_odgovor);
                    if (f.equals(s)){
                        tocan = true;
                        bt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        tocan = false;
                        bt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        Button newbutton = (Button) findViewById(id_odgovor);
                        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    timer.cancel();
                        if (tocan){
                            rezultat++;
                            timer.cancel();
                            Toast.makeText(beze2.this, "Tocan odgovor, vas score je " + Integer.toString(rezultat), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), beze2.class);
                            i.putExtra("REZULTAT", Integer.toString(rezultat));
                            i.putExtra("EXTRA_M", strin);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(beze2.this, "Netocan odgovor, vas konacni score je " + Integer.toString(rezultat), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally{
                                upisiDatoteku("Guest", rezultat);
                                Intent i = new Intent(beze2.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                }

            });

        }
        timer.start();

    }

    private void upisiDatoteku(String s, int rez){

        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String newOne = s + "\t" + Integer.toString(rez);
            fos.write(newOne.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class myCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

        public myCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            text.setText("Time's up");
            myHandler.post(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        Intent i = new Intent(beze2.this, beze.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        Toast.makeText(beze2.this, "Isteklo vam je vrijeme, Vas score je " + Integer.toString(rezultat), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        upisiDatoteku("Guest",rezultat);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int i = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            text.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to finish first activity?, I mean in onclick method, first finish activity then start new activity It means actually restart activity.

Comment: Yes, I tried but unfortunately the effect is the same. Do you have another idea.